# query not pulling in select box value, oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using application builder and setting up select boxes to populate a query that spits out into a report below, I'm having a problem with one populating though, and I can't immediatly see why;

Here's how I'm referencing;

AND  CINEMA.LOCATION  = :pticketstown

this works fine and pulls in the choice from the select box which is popluated from a query on the cinema table, however when I try and do the same thing for another table, try and pull in a film title from a select box choice - it doesnt seem to work, the rport says no output.

Im setting up the select box the same way, and its pulling in the films, but when as soon as I reference it in the sql report, the ouptut is empty.

FILM.FILM_TITLE  = :pfilm

Has nayone any thoughts on why it would fail on something that uses the same method ? is it a case that the value isn't bieng passed across? I'm a little stumped if that's the case as I set it up the same way as the working one.

Thanks for looking

Comment: I have just realised that it breaks whent the fields that are being compared have spaces in..ie film titles. Not sure how to get around this though? wondering if 'like' would be the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from the sound of it  you are using application express? Have you turned on debugging to see exactly what is being passed? It might be encoding the spaces or something.

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange that the two, seemingly similar queries would behave differently. Do you have access to the actual sql produced? If so, i would try running that against your db direct through the command line or sql developer if you have it.